# Read the band value and Write the band value in Raster(.tif) using QGIS python

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have written a plugin in QGIS 3 to read the band value of a pixel or from a textbox and update the value to the selected pixels. When I'm updating a single pixel or smaller group, the script is working fine. When I'm updating for a large group of pixels, the script terminating from the half way and shows the error like  ".tif file is not regonised file format..."

In the below screen, I have entered band value 5 and updated the same for small area. When I tried the same for bigger area, it applies partially and shows the error as mentioned above.

[image]

Below is the code used for read, write and close the raster (.tif) file.

```
def change_cell_value(self, vals, x=None, y=None):

    if not x:
        x = self.px
    else:
        pass
    if not y:
        y =self.py
    else:
        pass
    self.gdal_raster = gdal.Open(self.raster.source(), GA_Update) #Read
    for nr in range(1, min(4, self.bandCount + 1)):
        s = vals[nr-1]
        rbuf = s.tostring()
        self.bands[nr]['data'].WriteRaster(x, y, 1, 1, rbuf, buf_type=self.bands[nr]['qtype']) #Write
        self.bands[nr]['data'] = None
        self.bands[nr] = None
    self.gdal_raster = None  #Close
    self.raster.setCacheImage(None)
    self.raster.triggerRepaint()
    self.prepare_gdal_raster(True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update it to another pixel"? Do you mean instead value? If possible, post all your code not just opening of the raster.

Comment: I have updated the above content with screenshot please refer.

Comment: What's the variable type of self.bands[1]? how did you extract individual bands to arrays? It's quite hard to debug with partial code.